# Insert a large subset of one table to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

A rewrite a Rails 2 application to Rails 3.

Can I do the sql statement

```
INSERT INTO visits (col1, col2) SELECT col_a, col_b FROM clicks WHERE import_id = 1
```

with arel and ruby (without a loop). My first thought was, that I could do

```
Visit.create(Import.clicks)
```

or

```
Visit.create(Click.select("col1, col2").where("import_id = 1"))
```

or

```
Visit.insert(Click.select("col1, col2").where("import_id = 1"))
```

sadly that didn't work. Does anyone know more?

Comment: What is wrong with executing the SQL you've written directly?

Comment: Whenever possible you should stay in the same programming language. E.g. a caching framework would not know, that it should update the import.visits etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [ar-extensions](https://rubygems.org/gems/ar-extensions). It should let you do this:

```
Visit.insert_select(
  :into => [:col1, :col2],
  :select => [:col_a, :col_b],
  :from => :clicks,
  :conditions => ['import_id = ?', 1],
)
```

Check out [the documentation](http://snowgiraffe.com/rdocs/ar-extensions/files/ar-extensions/lib/ar-extensions/insert_select_rb.html) for the details.

Comment: ok, it would do the job in rails 2, activerecord-import does the job somehow in rails 3